# How can i get paypal to automatically create and send the invoices needed for a product just sold?

Tags: wordpress, api, paypal, sdk, invoice

My costumers have already submitted their invoice data and I stored them in the wp db of the wp site. I already use a paypal payment "button" but I would like to implement the automatic invoice feature. I've searched and studied the paypal developer website and watched some videos on youtube but I only got confused. Here are my questions:

1- Is the sdk invoice what I'm looking for? 
if not
2- Can I create what i need with the NewApplication tools on apps.paypal.com
if not
3- Can I reach my goal with the CreateAndSendInvoice API Operation?

They might not even be 3 different methods, that's how cofused I am right now.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to use the CreateAndSendInvoice API but currently PayPal doesn't have anything to automatically send invoices. PayPal offers the subscriptions or recurring billing which automatically charges the customers.

I hope this helps.

Comment: mmm... But the createAndSendInvoice (let's call it CASI) API accepts values regarding the seller and the buyers email and all the other informations needed to invoice... If I gather the information from my website database and pass it to the API call shouldn't it work? Does the CASI just shows the form for the required invoice infos so the buyer can fill it? Otherwise I don't get why bother creating all these methods to invoice if in the end I still have to manually fill all the damn forms... XD